# Does &mut T implements Borrow<T> break a mutable reference rule?

Tags: rust

`&mut T` implements `Borrow<T>`，so `(&mut T).borrow()` will create `&T`. Does this break the rule that “if we have one mutable reference, we can not have any other references (mutable or not)”?

```rust
use std::borrow::Borrow;
let mut n = 1;
let r1: &mut i32 = &mut n;
let r2: &i32 = r1.borrow();

println!("log: {r1} {r2}");
```

The code compiles, but if I change `r1.borrow()` to `&n`, it will report error

What's the exact rule of the reference system?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4a1382eb1ebf724c5bbd3056dc681ced)

Comment: While the `r2` borrow exists `*r1` is unusable: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7aa721b8cf00d1daa1193143e12e6e42)

Answer (score 2):

This is more general than `Borrow`. You can do the same thing with regular references:

```rs
let r1: &mut i32 = &mut n;
let r2: &i32 = &*r1;
```

When you think about it, it's very necessary to be able to make immutable references from mutable references. For example, you need it to call `&self` methods on `&mut` variables.

But rust still ensures you aren't using the `mut` property of the variable.

Things you can do:

- Give out more `&` references

  ```rs
  let r3: &i32 = &*r1;
  ```
- Use it behind another `&` reference

  ```rs
  fn takes_ref_mut_ref(_: &&mut i32) {}
  takes_ref_mut_ref(&r1);
  ```
- Copy types that implement `Copy`

  ```rs
  let r4 = *r1;
  ```
- Deref to `&` (this does `&*r1` implicitly)

  ```rs
  fn print_three(a: &i32, b: &i32, c: &i32) {
      println!("{a} {b} {c}")
  }
  print_three(r1, r2, r3);
  ```

Things you can't do:

- Implicitly use it as a `&&`

  ```rs
  fn takes_ref_ref(_: &&i32) {}
  takes_ref_ref(&r1);
  ```
- Use it as `&mut` directly

  ```rs
  fn print_three_mut(a: &mut i32, b: &i32, c: &i32) {
      println!("{a} {b} {c}")
  }
  print_three_mut(r1, r2, r3);
  ```
- And obviously, mutate the variable

  ```rs
  *r1 = 5;
  ```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ca1437cb5a28961b1bbe4055cd09e559)

Comment: thanks for answering. I tried to change the code `let r2: &i32  = &*r1;` to `let r2: &i32  = &n;`, it report an compiler error,  they both create an immutable reference,  so what's the difference ?

Comment: While `r1` exists, you can't access `n`. There isn't really anything wrong in this particular case, but it's simpler to just forbid all usage of `n` than to check that `n` hasn't been used in a mutable way yet.

Comment: so the text does not describe the error accuratly？the mut reference hide the owner in fact (we may should call it the `only` reference)，and the check for mutable use happen while using it, not declaring it, the code `println!("log: {r1} {r2}");` take the two both as immutable refs ?

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding, but when you don't use it in `println`, `r1` gets dropped immediately after creating it so that `n` is usable again. And `println` adds `&` to all arguments, making it `&&mut` like the `fn takes_ref_mut_ref` in my answer.